# Error When Selecting From Join

Tags: mysql

Does anyone know why I am getting an error from this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING establishment_id
WHERE i.bla = e.bla;
```

mysql-workbench is giving me a squiggly line under establishment_id in line 1 and is reporting a syntax error, but I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: Do you have `establishment_id` in both tables as same name ?

Comment: `USING (establishment_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need brackets:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING (establishment_id)
WHERE i.bla = e.bla;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM individual AS i LEFT JOIN establishment AS e USING establishment_id
on i.bla = e.bla;
```